# query is getting UTC timestamp from the database but local time is stored in the database

Tags: django, django-models

For some reason my queryset is returning a UTC time, however in the database the time it is supposed to be getting is local time. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks for your help

The last_checkin_time method is what gets the user's last checkin timestamp from the database, and right now I just have it posting in my toggle method in the time_delta variable so I can see what value its getting. (once i get this timezone thing figured out the time_delta will be an actual time delta)

Heres my model manager

```
class UserActivityManager(models.Manager):

    def current(self, user):
        current_obj = self.get_queryset().filter(user=user).order_by('-timestamp').first()
        return current_obj

    def last_checkin_time(self, user):
        last_activity_time = self.get_queryset().order_by('-timestamp').filter(user=user, activity="checkin").first()
        return last_activity_time

    def toggle(self, user):
        last_item = self.current(user)
        activity = "checkin"
        time_delta = None
        last_checkin = self.last_checkin_time(user)
        if last_item is not None:
            if last_item.timestamp <= tz.localize(datetime.datetime.now()):
                pass
            if last_item.activity == "checkin":
                activity = "checkout"
                time_delta = last_checkin.timestamp

        obj = self.model(
                user=user,
                activity=activity,
                time_delta = time_delta,
        )
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

And heres what the table in my database looks like (focusing on the time_delta field in the last few rows)

[image]

EDIT:

Also I should mention the timestamp field in my model is set to auto_now_add=True ie.
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Not sure if this is causing the problem

Comment: I don't think DB saves the local time. I think the ***DB client (the table in the screenshot)*** showing it in your local time

Comment: So I probably need to set the timezone sometime after i get it from the database? That was what I was thinking too but when i try to do something like use tz.localize(last_checkin.timestamp) for the value I get the error "Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tz.localize(last_checkin.timestamp) I needed to use tz.normalize(last_checkin.timestamp). It seems since the timestamp was already set to UTC I needed to change it with the normalize method, rather than the localize